# git `merge --squash` does not add "Merge" header to commit

Tags: git, merge

I was wondering how all the tools know what branches/commits are merged until I found a "Merge" header in the commit.

My question is: why a `git merge --squash` does not add that header, while `git merge` does?

In other words: why do I see a merge edge when merging with `git merge` while there is no edge with `git merge --squash`?

Thank you.

**some amended information:**

With "merge-header" I mean the second line in `git log` after merging:

```
commit 7777777
Merge: 0123456 9876543
Author: Some Body <...>
Date:   Fri ....
```

... while a `git merge --squash` will **not** produce that line and my assumption is that git gui tools reads that header to be able to draw that 'merge edge' see the following image.

[image]

My question is again the same, see above.

Comment: I've amended my answer (and want to keep it as is), but the super-short answer is: "do not record the merge link" is exactly what `--squash` *means*. That's the only real effect of `--squash`. If you *do* want the merge recorded, *don't* use `--squash`. It's not just the GUI tools, it's a fundamental consequence of the way Git constructs commit DAGs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### TL;DR: `git merge --squash` merges (verb), but does not make a merge (noun).

The "merge header" you mention is not in the commits in that form.  Instead, it's just something that `git log` prints when it comes across a *merge commit*.  To really cement this idea, let's look at what merging *does*—what "to merge" means as a *verb*—and what a merge *is*.  More properly, let's look at what a *merge commit* is, or what "merge" means as an [*adjective*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/adjective) modifying the word "commit".  We'll be lazy, like good Git users, though, and shorten it from "merge commit" to "a merge", making it a noun.

### Merge as an noun

Let's look at the noun usage first, since that's simpler.  In Git, a *merge commit* is simply a commit with at least two parent commits.  It really is that simple.  Every commit has some number of parents.  A *root* commit has zero parents (and most repositories have only one root commit, which is the first commit ever made, which obviously cannot have had a parent commit).  Most ordinary commits have just one parent, and all the other commits have two or more parents<sup>1</sup> and are therefore merge commits.  Then we shorten the phrase "merge commit" to just "a merge", changing "merge" from an adjective (modifying "commit") to a noun (meaning "a merge commit").

If a *merge commit* is a commit with two parents, then `git merge` must make merge commits, and *to merge* should mean "to make a merge commit"—and it does, but *only sometimes*.  We will see *when*—and more importantly, *why*—soon.

---

<sup>1</sup>Other VCSes may stop at two.  Mercurial does, for instance: no hg commit ever has *more* than two parents.  Git, however, allows any commit to have any number of parents.  A Git commit with three or more parents is called an *octopus merge*, and normally these commits are made using `git merge -s octopus` or equivalent, e.g., `git merge topic1 topic2 topic3`: running `git merge` with extra commit specifiers implies `-s octopus`.  These do nothing that cannot be done using a series of two-parent merges, so Git's octopus merges do not give it more power than Mercurial, but octopus merges are sometimes convenient, and good for showing off your Git Fu. :-)

---

### Merge as a verb

The verb form of *to merge* is much more complicated—or at least, it is in Git.  We can distinguish between two major forms of merging as well: there's the act of merging *source code changes*, and then there's the act of merging *branches*.  (This brings in the question of "what is a branch".  There's a lot more to this question than you might think, so see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452))  Many Git commands can do the verb kind of merging, including `git cherry-pick` and `git revert`, both of which are essentially a form of `git apply -3`.<sup>2</sup>  Of course `git merge` is the most obvious way to do it, and when it does, you get the verb form of merging changes.

#### Merging changes

Merging source changes is more properly called "three way merging".  For more about this, see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_(version_control)#Three-way_merge)<sup>3</sup> or [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4130766/1256452) to [Why is a 3-way merge advantageous over a 2-way merge?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4129049/1256452)  The details can get quite complex, but the *goal* of this merge process is simple enough: we want to *combine* changes made to some common base, i.e., given some starting point *B*, we find changes *C<sub>1</sub>* and *C<sub>2</sub>* and combine them to make a single new change *C<sub>3</sub>*, then add that change to the base *B* to get a new version.

In Git, the act of merging sources—of doing the three-way merge itself—uses Git's *index*, also called the "staging area".  Normally, the index has just one entry for each file that will go into the next commit.  When you `git add` a file, you tell Git to update the staged version of the file, replacing the one in the current index, or if the file was previously "untracked", adding the file *to* the index so that it is now tracked and also staged for the next commit.  During the merge process, however, the index has up to *three* entries for each file: one from the merge base version, one entry for the file-version to be treated as change #1 (also called "ours"), and one for change #2 ("theirs").  If Git is able to combine the changes on its own, it replaces<sup>4</sup> the three entries with one regular (staged-for-commit) entry.  Otherwise it stops with a conflict, leaving the conflict marked in the work-tree version of the file.  You must resolve the conflict yourself (presumably editing the file in the process), and use `git add` to replace the three special conflicted-merge index versions with the one normal staged version.

Once all conflicts are resolved, Git will be able to make a new commit.

#### Making a merge commit

The last thing a normal, merge-making `git merge` does is to make the merge commit.  Again, if there were no conflicts, Git can just do this on its own: `git merge` merges the changes, `git add`s each merge-result to update the staged files, and runs `git commit` for you.  Or, if there were conflicts, you fix them, *you* run `git add`, and *you* run `git commit`.  In all cases, it's actually `git commit`, rather than `git merge` itself, that makes the merge commit.

This last part is actually very easy, since the index / staging-area is all set up.  Git just makes a commit as usual, except that instead of giving it the current (`HEAD`) commit's ID as its one single parent, it gives it at least *two* parent commit IDs: the first one is the `HEAD` commit as usual, and the rest come from a file left behind by `git merge` (`.git/MERGE`).

---

<sup>2</sup>The `-3` in `git apply -3`, which can be spelled out as `--3way`, directs `git apply` to use the `index` string in `git diff` output to construct a merge base if needed.  When doing this with `git cherry-pick` and `git revert`, to turn them into merges (instead of straightforward patches), Git winds up using the parent commit of the cherry-picked or reverted commit.  It's worth noting here that Git does this only on a *per file* basis, *after* treating the patch just as a simple patch has failed.  Using the parent commit's file as a base version for a three-way merge will normally help only if that commit is an ancestor of the current (HEAD) commit.  If it's not actually such an ancestor, combining the diff generated from "base" to HEAD with the patch being applied is probably not helpful.  Still, Git will do it as a fallback.

<sup>3</sup>As usual for Wikipedia, I spotted some minor inaccuracies in it just now—for instance, it's possible to have more than two DAG LCAs—but don't have time to work on it, and it's not a bad overview.

<sup>4</sup>Often, it never bothers to make the conflicted entries in the first place.  Git will, if possible, short-cut-away even the `git diff` phase.  Suppose for instance that the base commit has four files in it: `u.txt` is unchanged from base in either commit, `one.txt` is changed from base to `HEAD` but not from base to the other commit, `two.txt` is changed from base to the other commit but not from base to `HEAD`, and `three.txt` is changed in both.  Git will simply copy `u.txt` straight through, take `one.txt` from `HEAD`, take `two.txt` from the other commit, and only bother to generate diffs, then try to merge them, for `three.txt`.  This goes pretty fast, but does mean that if you have your own special three-way-merge program for these files, it *never gets run* for `u.txt`, `one.txt`, and `two.txt`, only for `three.txt`.

I am not sure off-hand whether Git makes the multiple index entries before attempting the merging of diffs, or after attempting and failing.  It does, however, have to make all three entries before running custom merge drivers.

---

### Non-merge "merges"

The above sequence—check out some commit (usually a branch tip), run `git merge` on another commit (usually some *other* branch tip), find a suitable merge base, make two sets of diffs, combine the diffs, and commit the result—is how normal merges work, and how Git makes merge commits.  We merge (as a verb) the changes, and make a merge (adjective) commit (or "make a merge", noun).  But, as we noted earlier, `git merge` doesn't always do this.

#### Fast-forwards

Sometimes `git merge` says it's "doing a fast-forward merge".  This is a little bit of a misnomer, because "fast-forwarding" is more accurately considered a property of a *branch label change*, in Git.  There are two other commands that use this property, `git fetch` and `git push`, which distinguish between a normal (or "fast-forward") branch update and a "forced" update.  A proper discussion of fast-forwarding requires getting into the details of the commit graph, so all I will say here is that it occurs when you move a branch label from commit *O* (old) to commit *N* (new), and commit *N* has commit *O* as an ancestor.

When `git merge` detects that your merge argument is one of these cases—that `HEAD` is an ancestor of this other commit—it will normally invoke this fast-forward operation instead.  In this case, Git just uses the commit you told it to merge.  There's no *new* commit at all, just the re-use of some *existing* commit.  Git does not make a merge commit, nor does it do any merging-as-a-verb.  It just changes you over to the new commit, almost as if by `git reset --hard`: moving the current branch label and updating the work-tree.

You can suppress this fast-forward action with `--no-ff`.<sup>5</sup>  In this case, `git merge` will make a new merge commit even if a fast-forward is possible.  You get no merge-as-a-verb *action* (there's no work to do) but you *do* get a new merge *commit*, and Git updates your work-tree to match.

#### Squash merge is not a merge

Note that we have covered two of three cases here:

- verb form plus adjective/noun form: a normal merge
- adjective/noun form of merge, but no verb: a merge that was fast-forward-able, but you ran `git merge --no-ff`

The missing third case is verb-without-noun: how do we get the *action* of a merge, combining changes, without the noun/adjective form of a merge *commit*?  This is where "squash merges" come in.  Running `git merge --squash <commit-specifier>` tells Git to do the merge action as usual, but *not* to record the other branch / commit-ID, so that the final `git commit` makes a normal, non-merge, single-parent commit.

That's really it—that's all it does!  It just makes a normal, non-merge commit at the end.  Oddly, it forces *you* to make that commit, instead of making it on its own.  (There is no fundamental reason that it has to do this, and I don't know why the Git authors chose to make it behave this way.)  But these are all *mechanisms*, not *policies*: they tell you *how* to make various kinds of commits, but not which ones you *should* make, or when, or—most important—*why*.

---

<sup>5</sup>You can tell `git merge` that it should *only* proceed if it can fast-forward: `git merge --ff-only`.  If the new commit is fast-forward-able, `git merge` updates to it.  Otherwise it simply fails.  I made an alias, `git mff`, that does this, since normally I want to `git fetch` and then see whether I need to merge, rebase, make a new branch entirely, or whatever.  If I *can* fast-forward, I don't need to do anything else, so if `git mff` works, I'm done.

---

### What kind of merge to use, when, why

The *why* question is hard, and like all philosophy questions, has no one right answer (but definitely a bunch of wrong ones :-) ).  Consider this fact: Every time you use `git merge` at all, you *could* have done something different and gotten the same *source code* to go with your newest commit.  There are three successful outcomes for a `git merge` (that is, a merge where you do not `git merge --abort` to end it, but rather conclude it successfully):

- fast-forward: no new commit; the source is that of an existing commit.
- true merge: new commit; the source is the combined source.
- squash merge: new commit; the source is the combined source.

The only difference between these three (aside from the obvious "no new commit at all" for the first one) is the *record* they leave behind in the commit *graph*.<sup>6</sup>  A fast-forward obviously leaves *no* record: the graph is unchanged from before, because you added nothing.  If that's what you want, that's what you should use.  In a repository where you are following someone else's work and never doing anything of your own, this is probably what you want.  It is also what you will get by default, and Git will "just work" for you.<sup>7</sup>

If you do a regular merge, that leaves a record of the merge.  All the existing commits remain exactly as they are, and Git adds one new commit, with two<sup>8</sup> parents.  Anyone coming along later will see just who did what, when, how, etc.  If this is what you want, this is what you should do.  Of course, some tools (like `git log`) will show who did what, when, etc., which—by showing a complete picture of all of history—may obscure the Big Picture view with all the little details.  That's both the up-side and the down-side, in other words.

If you do a squash merge, that leaves *no* record of the merge.  You make a new commit that picks up every merge-as-a-verb *action*, but the new commit is not a merge-as-a-noun.  Anyone coming along later will see all the work that went in, but not where it came from.  Tools like `git log` *cannot* show the little details, and you—and everyone else—will get *only* a Big Picture.  Again, that is both the up-side and the down-side.  But the down-side is perhaps a bit bigger, because if you find that you *need* those details later, they are *not there*.  They are not only not there in the `git log` view, they are also not there for a future `git merge`.

If you are *never* going to do a future `git merge` of the squashed-in changes, that might not be a problem.  If you plan to delete that branch entirely, giving up all the individual changes *as* individuals and keeping only the single collective squash-merge change, the "bad" part of doing the `git merge --squash` has essentially zero "badness value".  If you intend to keep working on that branch, though, and merge it again later, that particular badness value increases hugely.

If you are doing squash merges specifically to make `git log` output "look nicer" (show more of a Big Picture instead of obscuring it with too many details), note that there are various `git log` options designed to be *selective* about *which commits* it shows.  In particular, `--first-commit` avoids traversing merged-in branches entirely, showing only the merge itself and then continuing down the "main line" of the commit graph.  You can also use `--simplify-by-decoration` to omit all but *tagged* commits, for instance.

---

<sup>6</sup>Well, also in your reflogs; but your reflogs are private, and eventually expire, so we'll just ignore them.

<sup>7</sup>This assumes that they—whoever "they" are—do not "rewind" their commit graph, by rebasing or removing published commits.  If they do remove published commits, your Git will by default merge those commits back in, as if they were your own work.  This is one reason anyone publishing a Git repository should think hard about "rewinding" such commits.

<sup>8</sup>Assuming no fancy octopus merges.

Comment: Note: `git apply` is quite different from a merge, in that it does not have a merge base. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/38989749/6309.

Comment: sorry, but I do also not find the answer to my question. I know what merge or squash merge does.

Comment: @VonC: `git apply` with `-3` will use the `index` strings to produce a merge base. I should fix that in the main text though.

Comment: @Aitch: now that you've edited your question I can answer more directly: the "merge header" you are talking about is just what `git log` prints when it comes across a *merge commit*.  It prints `Merge:` followed by the parent SHA-1 IDs. If you do not have a merge commit—i.e., you do not have a merge-as-a-noun—then then there is no recorded merge information.

Comment: @torek okay so merge squash is quite misleading. If I want a real merge without microcommits and with merge meta information, I should use `git merge --no-ff ...` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/14865661/4469738). It's actually very strange, that merge tries a fast-forward first as 99% of all hotfix master develop merges are no fast-forwards, and one day there is a fast-forward and suddenly there are some strange microcommits I don't want to see in release branches. I my case I used squash merge as I didn't know that it's not a real commit. Next time I will use --no-ff. Thank you!

Comment: "so merge squash is quite misleading": exactly. I really wish Git used a different command to make these. I lost that battle long ago though, before I even started using Git. :-) (I think `git checkout` and `git reset` deserve to be split up into separate front end commands, for instance.)

Comment: This answer deserves more than just one upvote! It's almost a compendium of merge mechanisms including discussions and humour. Let's call it 'The Git Merger's Guide to the Galaxy'.

Answer (score 1):

**Git merge**  - will merge all the commits from the branch to the master if these commits are not present in the master [preserving the commit order]. It also adds a new commit id showing the merge - **Merge branch 'branch-name' of http://repo-name into "master"**

now **Git merge --squash** - finds all the files that are different from master and marks them as modified. now when you commit these they go under a new commit id with the message that you provide, like a normal commit.

Comment: Please read my question. I know what merge or merge squash does, but how is a gui tool able to draw merge edges with simple merges, while it is not with merge squash? I amend some more information which should now be more clear.