# Why do subsequent merges from one branch to master end up in conflicts?

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I want:

- to work on `develop` and make all my changes there (or in other feature branches that are merged into `develop`)
- to merge `develop` into `master` when I want to release (squashing all commits since the last time I did that)

But I'm getting merge conflicts when I merge `develop` into `master`.

Here's a small example of my workflow that reproduces what is a problem to me:

1. Create empty repo, clone it

   ```
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp$ mkdir repo.git
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp$ cd repo.git/
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo.git$ git init --bare
   Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/repo.git/
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo.git$ cd /tmp
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp$ git clone repo.git repo
   Cloning into 'repo'...
   warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.
   done.
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp$ cd repo
   ```
2. Now make some commits to master:

   ```
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ echo 'blah blah blah' > readme
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ echo 'version: 1' >manifest
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ git add manifest readme 
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ git commit -m "initial commit"
   [master (root-commit) 5c7f827] initial commit
    2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
    create mode 100644 manifest
    create mode 100644 readme
   ```
3. Now branch off `develop`

   ```
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ git checkout -b develop
   Switched to a new branch 'develop'
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ echo "testing" >work
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ git add work
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ git commit -m "working on work"
   [develop f22b31b] working on work
    1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
    create mode 100644 work
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ echo "more work" >>work 
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ git commit -am "still work"
   [develop 6a8981f] still work
    1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
   ```
4. Here is a modification of a file that's already tracked on `master`:

   ```
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ sed -i 's/version: 1/version: 2/' manifest 
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ git commit -am "version bump"
   [develop de2866b] version bump
    1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
   ```
5. Back to master, merge all commits in `develop` and squash them:

   ```
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ git checkout master
   Switched to branch 'master'
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ git merge develop --squash 
   Updating 5c7f827..de2866b
   Fast-forward
   Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
    manifest | 2 +-
    work     | 2 ++
    2 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
    create mode 100644 work
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ git commit 
   [master 04528f9] Squashed commit of the following:     version bump     still work     working on work
    2 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
    create mode 100644 work
   ```
6. Now back to work:

   ```
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ git checkout develop 
   Switched to branch 'develop'
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ echo "still working" >>work 
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ git commit -am "continued work"
   [develop 81e3d08] continued work
    1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
   ```
7. Then the change that in my opinion should be fine but will prove to break things:

   ```
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ sed -i 's/version: 2/version: 3/' manifest 
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ git commit -am "version bump"
   [develop 83b77fb] version bump
    1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
   ```
8. Back to `master`, expecting a dumb merge that didn't happen:

   ```
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ git checkout master 
   Switched to branch 'master'
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ git merge develop --squash 
   Auto-merging work
   CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in work
   Auto-merging manifest
   CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in manifest
   Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
   Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
   ```
9. Here's one conflict:

   ```
   bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ cat manifest 
   <<<<<<< HEAD
   version: 2
   =======
   version: 3
   >>>>>>> develop
   ```

So my questions/reflections:

1. Why didn't it fast forward?
2. I know I can force the merge with `git merge develop --squash -s recursive -Xtheirs`, but do I *need* to do that *each time* I will merge `develop` into `master`?
3. Is my workflow wrong?
4. After merging `develop` into `master`, should I merge back `master` into `develop`? Isn't that an infinite loop?
5. Why did the merge in step 5 worked when the one in step 8 didn't? It's just a change of `1` -> `2` (OK) and then `2` -> `3` (KO). Should be fine for me!
6. Is there any merge strategy or any other option that may get me to what I want?

Bonus question:
when squashing, git is nice enough to compile all the commit messages before committing the squash. But that contains all the commit messages since the branches forked (e.g. step 3 above).
**How to get only the commit messages since the last time I merged develop into master?** (e.g. step 5 above)

Note: [merging using a temporary branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4969679/334493) does what I want in terms of merging without conflicts, but it doesn't in the sense where I don't have all the commit messages squashed into one.

Comment: At step 1? I don't know actually, I usually have the repo stored elsewhere and cloned over SSH, so I reproduced that. But that's not the point.

Comment: [This may not seem like a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39096500/1256452), and my answer is long, but you should read the entire answer and then consider whether you want to continue to use squash, which is not a merge. If you *do* want to keep using squash, you probably want to abandon each branch once it is squashed. (Toss the old one and start a new one, perhaps with the same name, even.)

Comment: I had already read it. But the end of your comment hints at the problem here: I can't merge develop into master (squashing the commits) several times in a row without cleanly rebranching develop from master each time. (e.g toss the old one and start a new one, with possibly the same name). Which tells me that something is wrong, which is probably my workflow. :(

Comment: The difference is that with a proper merge commit git has recorded that you have already merged in these changes. If you're doing a rebase/squash instead you apply the same changes again, the difference now is that you already have some of these changes in master, thus you get a conflict. In short, if you're not going to abandon the branch when you rebase/squash it, don't rebase/squash it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git \`merge --squash\` does not add "Merge" header to commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096500/git-merge-squash-does-not-add-merge-header-to-commit)

Comment: Thanks all for all the information and links. My guess is that torek and Lasse nailed it: don't squash and reuse the branch. I have to question my workflow and find something that's clean in git and fits my needs.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'm really grateful you took the time to read my question, parse it and help me out. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As torek and Lasse pointed out in the comments, I made some wrong assumptions:

- squashing the commits when merging doesn't create a merge commit. That was the main problem I guess
- when squashing the commits during a merge, the expected behavior after that is to dump the branch that provided the commits
- when working with two branches in parallel an merging one into the other on a regular basis, one shall create commit merges

All the information linked in the comments above helped a lot, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3264341/334493) particularly fits my needs.

What I wanted was:

- work in parallel
- merge, creating a merge commit (hence no squash)
- have all the commit messages in the merge commit (instead of the dumb `Merge branch xxx`): this was solved using the `prepare-commit-message` hook

Here's the result of a dummy repo with exactly what I wanted for the workflow:

```
bicou@dikkenek:/tmp/repo$ git log --decorate --oneline --graph
*   182fb11 (HEAD, master) Merge details:
|\  
| * 1cdba95 (develop) version bump v4
| * d12d9ce work on v4 another feature
| * 70bb9f6 work on v4
* |   ee715de Merge details:
|\ \  
| |/  
| * 965356c work again on v3
| * 3f12856 work on dev v3
* |   37649d4 Merge branch 'develop'
|\ \  
| |/  
| * 0ef71dd work work on v2
| * 84b5069 continued work on v2
* |   5522eae Merge branch 'develop'
|\ \  
| |/  
| * b3e545e work again on develop
| * 0960273 work on develop 1
|/  
* 6515de5 initial commit
```

Each commit in `master`:

- is a merge commit
- the commit message is the list of the commit messages in develop since the last merge, and I can customize it in vim when running `git commit`.

*(the `Merge branch 'develop'` commits were created before I used the hook, and the `Merge details` commits were created with the hook using the simple `git m develop` + `git commit` which is awesome)*

If torek or Lasse want to post their own answer and get credit from it, they definitely should!