# Is `git merge` able to display every change (w.r. to a common ancestor) as merge conflict?

Tags: git, merge

Assume we have a file `common_ancestor` (`master`)

```
ok
ok
ok
ok
ok
```

From there, we change and commit `master` to

```
ok
change not ok (looking back)
ok
ok
ok
latest change
ok
```

Now we have a better idea, checkout `common_ancestor` and change it to

```
ok
ok
ok
This is a really good change
ok
ok
```

and commit in a new branch `dev`. As I need some developments from `master`, I want to merge `dev` into `master` but I want to decide for every change whether to keep or not. I tried

`git checkout master`
`git merge dev --no-ff --no-commit`

But I did not get what I `expected`. What I am looking for is something like:

```
ok
<<<<HEAD
change not ok (looking back)
====
>>>> HASH
ok
ok
<<<<HEAD
====
This is a really good change
>>>> HASH
ok
<<<<HEAD
latest change
====
>>>> HASH
```

where **conflict markers** are visible (see [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge)).

**Edit**: What I have seen, `git merge dev --no-ff --no-commit` does not highlight the changes - @VonC explained why there are no conflict markers visible (because there are no conflicts!).

Comment: Perhaps a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235010/how-to-prevent-an-automerge-using-git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case, merging `dev` to `master` would simply:

- add the change from `dev` "`This is a really good change`"
- keep the change introduced in `master` "`change not ok (looking back)`"

That is because those changes were not made at the same spot in the file: there is no concurrent modification at the same line.
That means there is no conflict.

If you want to have a look after a merge (but before the merge *commit*), you [can set up a custom merge driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5091756/6309).

```
[merge "verify"]
        name = merge and verify driver
        driver = ./merge-and-verify-driver %A %O %B
```

You can associate that driver to your files in a [.gitattributes file](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes).

```
*.R merge=merge and verify driver
```

With `merge-and-verify-driver.sh` a script which always return 1, in order to indicate that there was a conflict, even if the merge was actually resolved without conflicts (which is the case here: no conflict in your merge).

```
#!/bin/bash
git merge-file "${1}" "${2}" "${3}"
exit 1
```

Note: In case of conflicts, you will have more information with:

```
git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

Comment: To see an example of concurrent modification: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38989749/6309

Comment: I understand the missing conflict markers now. What if all my files are `.R` files? How can I tell git that, for a specific file, I would like "to review" first? If I understand the answer in your link correctly, they specify a file extension in the git attributes. Is a custom command like `git merge --verify dev` possible? (I appologize, if the question is stupid - I am quite new to git.)

Comment: @Christoph In a .gitattribute, you can associate your custom merge driver to a category of files (as in https://gist.github.com/dpwright/2657379) I have edited my answer.

Comment: But then, all my `.R` files "need to be reviewed", that is, I cannot decide whether I want to have a look at a merge or not? (Backround: In most(!) cases git does exactly what one would like - it would be really bad if I make git worse / slow)

Comment: @Christoph Actually, with that merge driver, the merge will occur, not the merge commit. That gives you the opportunity to review only the files you want, before adding and committing everything.

Comment: @Christoph just to be clear: the merge will not stop at each files. It will merge all files, then stop in "failure" (exit 1). Then a git status will indicate if there are any conflicts. And if not, you can review the files you want.

Answer (score 2):

As @VonC pointed out, it is not correct to treat differences in two versions as conflicts. Therefore he answered my question. To reach my goal I used

```
git difftool -t=kdiff3 dev master
```

and the merge tool therein. In kdiff3, every difference is highlighted and you can choose which version for each line you want to keep.
See also [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-CkqiIPAzgQ) for a video-tutorial.

Comment: Yes, kdiff3 is useful here. Once the merge is completed (but not committed), you can use git diff on any modified file, and kdiff3 will allow you to complete the merge if needed.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to merge dev into master but I want to decide for every change whether to keep or not.

That calls for an interactive rebase:

```
git branch dev_rebase dev
git checkout dev_rebase
git rebase -i master
```

Then go ahead from there. `git help rebase`, looking for "interactive mode" should give you ideas. Simply delete lines (commits) you want to skip, and use `edit` if you want to take parts of a commit but need to edit the files.

If something goes horribly wrong, `dev` will be untouched, in any case.

```
# if happy:

git checkout master
git merge --no-ff dev_rebase

# for good measure:

git checkout dev
git rebase master
```

Comment: I fear I didn't work long enough with git: How do you proceed? When I type your command in git bash, a strange editor (MINGW64) opens and I am lost. See edit...

Comment: In that editor, git lists all commits (from master to the tip of your current branch). If you just exit it, git will replay all commits and you will end up where you started. The magic is in editing that file - you can delete lines (those commits will be skipped), you can reorder them (commits will be applied in the different order), or you can replace the command `pick` by something else, like `edit`. `git help rebase` explains it in greater detail.

Comment: I think your approach is different as rebase also does the merge for you - See my answer below and what I did in the end. Please let me know if I am wrong, then I will have a look at it again.